# Caused by: rx.exceptions.MissingBackpressureException

Tags: android, rx-java, kotlin

I have an other problem. This time I am facing this error `Caused by: rx.exceptions.MissingBackpressureException` during the execution of this code:

```
class UpdateHelper {
val numberOfFileToUpdate: PublishSubject<Int>

init {
    numberOfFileToUpdate = PublishSubject.create()
}

public fun startUpdate(): Observable<Int>{
    return getProducts().flatMap { products: ArrayList<Product> ->
            numberOfFileToUpdate.onNext(products.size)
            return@flatMap saveRows(products)
        }
}

private fun getProducts(): Observable<ArrayList<Product>> {
    return Observable.create {
        var products: ArrayList<Product> = ArrayList()
        var i = 0
        while (i++ < 100) {
            products.add(Product())
        }

        it.onNext(products)
        it.onCompleted()
    }
}


private fun saveRows(products: ArrayList<Product>): Observable<Int> {
    return Observable.create<Int> {
        var totalNumberOfRow = products.size

        while (totalNumberOfRow-- > 0){
            it.onNext(products.size - totalNumberOfRow)
            Thread.sleep(100)
        }
        it.onCompleted()
    }
}
```

}

The code is just a test code of two process. The first process gets a list of `Product` from the web, then those products are persist into the a local database within the app. This is the main idea.

The method `getProducts` do the work of getting the data, in this case I just create an ArrayList of 100 products. The `saveRows` do the persist work.

The `saveRows` methods emit juts an `Int` that represent the saved row. I am doing this because in the UI I have a progressbar reporting the progress.

From an other point of the app I call the method `startUpdate` and after a few items emitted I get the describe exception

```
at com.techbyflorin.rockapan.helpers.UpdateHelper$saveRows$1.call(UpdateHelper.kt:46)

at com.techbyflorin.rockapan.helpers.UpdateHelper$saveRows$1.call(UpdateHelper.kt:40)
```

I understand why this exception should be happening `https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Backpressure` but I do not know what I am doing wrong or how to solve it.

Can anybody advice me about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is your Observable source emits faster than the consumer consumes. It takes 100 ms to save each product. You can add onBackpressureBuffer().

```
UpdateHelper().startUpdate()
    .onBackpressureBuffer() // Add this
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe({
      Log.d(TAG, "next $it")
    }, {
      Log.d(TAG, it.message)
    }, {
    })
```

Also, you can try removing `Thread.sleep(100)`.

flatmap use [OperatorMerge](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/master/src/main/java/rx/internal/operators/OperatorMerge.java) ( `merge(map(func))`): you can see that in your case, `map`'s onNexts are sent faster than have been requested.