# OnErrorNotImplementedException Caused by: rx.exceptions.MissingBackpressureException

Tags: android, realm, rx-java, reactivex

I have an error when I call syncUsers() method.

```
rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException at rx.Observable$27.onError(Observable.java:8139)
    at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:157)
    at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:120)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorZip$Zip$InnerSubscriber.onError(OperatorZip.java:325)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorZip$Zip$InnerSubscriber.onNext(OperatorZip.java:333)
    at io.realm.rx.RealmObservableFactory$5$1.onChange(RealmObservableFactory.java:143)
    at io.realm.rx.RealmObservableFactory$5$1.onChange(RealmObservableFactory.java:139)
    at io.realm.RealmResults.notifyChangeListeners(RealmResults.java:1010)
    at io.realm.RealmResults.notifyChangeListeners(RealmResults.java:996)
    at io.realm.HandlerController.notifyRealmResultsCallbacks(HandlerController.java:303)
    at io.realm.HandlerController.notifySyncRealmResultsCallbacks(HandlerController.java:284)
    at io.realm.HandlerController.notifyTypeBasedListeners(HandlerController.java:275)
    at io.realm.HandlerController.notifyAllListeners(HandlerController.java:262)
    at io.realm.HandlerController.realmChanged(HandlerController.java:385)
    at io.realm.HandlerController.handleMessage(HandlerController.java:116)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: rx.exceptions.MissingBackpressureException
    at rx.internal.util.RxRingBuffer.onNext(RxRingBuffer.java:352)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorZip$Zip$InnerSubscriber.onNext(OperatorZip.java:331)
    at io.realm.rx.RealmObservableFactory$5$1.onChange(RealmObservableFactory.java:143) 
    at io.realm.rx.RealmObservableFactory$5$1.onChange(RealmObservableFactory.java:139) 
    at io.realm.RealmResults.notifyChangeListeners(RealmResults.java:1010) 
    at io.realm.RealmResults.notifyChangeListeners(RealmResults.java:996) 
    at io.realm.HandlerController.notifyRealmResultsCallbacks(HandlerController.java:303) 
    at io.realm.HandlerController.notifySyncRealmResultsCallbacks(HandlerController.java:284) 
    at io.realm.HandlerController.notifyTypeBasedListeners(HandlerController.java:275) 
    at io.realm.HandlerController.notifyAllListeners(HandlerController.java:262) 
    at io.realm.HandlerController.realmChanged(HandlerController.java:385) 
    at io.realm.HandlerController.handleMessage(HandlerController.java:116) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

The problem seems to come from the first operation.

```
public Observable<Void> syncUsers() {
            return client.getInstance().getUsers()
                .flatMap(new Func1<Users, Observable<Users>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<Users> call(final Users users) {

                        users.setIdentifier(PrefHelper.getUserName()); //primary key
                        final Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                            @Override
                            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                                realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(users);
                            }
                        });
                        realm.close();
                        return Observable.just(users);
                    }
                })
                .flatMap(new Func1<Users, Observable<Void>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<Void> call(final Users users) {
                        if (users != null && users.getUsers() != null) {
                            for (final User user : users.getUsers()) {
                                Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                                realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void execute(Realm realm) {
                                        UserFactory.attachParentUser(user);
                                        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(user);
                                    }
                                });
                                realm.close();
                            }
                        }
                        return Observable.empty();
                    }
                });

}
```

And the call :

```
 mGetUsersSubscription = new GetUsersRequest(getApplicationContext(),    mCurrentUser != null ? mCurrentUser.getIdentifier() : mUserIdToSearch, false).execute()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    //Do nothing
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    mFilesEmptyView.showError();
                    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Void aVoid) {
                    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    refreshDataFromDB();
                }
            });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34447356/caused-by-rx-exceptions-missingbackpressureexception?rq=1 did you check this out?

Answer (score 0):

1.) open transaction and THEN iterate and THEN commit.

Don't iterate, open transaction and commit.

2.) apply `onBackpressureLatest()` operator